# Strategy pattern to create objects?

Tags: java

Is it a good practice to pass a strategy instance (an interface implementation) to a method so that the method can return objects of a specific type based on the strategy instance type?

For example,

I have a method `getData(String x, String y)` but this needs to return objects of either `type A` or `type B`. Most of the stuff in this method is common and hence i'm thinking of reusing a single method.

I'm thinking of passing an extra parameter `TypeInterface t` and check type of this instance in the method and build objects of either `A` or `B`.

Comment: What's stopping you from implementing that method in each class ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not enough information you are providing here for good answer. Are `A` and `B` related to each either at all? What is logic that determines to return `A` or `B`?

Comment: Have you given a thought about using builder pattetn for creating complex object?

Comment: @Greggz code duplication.

Comment: @tsolakp What is logic that determines to return A or B?  the type of the parameter (using instanceOf() or by getting class name).

Comment: @notionquest yep, looks like i can make use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Most of the stuff in this method is common and hence i'm thinking of
>   reusing a single method.

You will make the client API more verbose and complex by introducing an additional parameter that besides is a class.
As alternative you could declare two distinct public methods with a difference in their naming and in their implementation you could rely on a common private method for the common processings.

For example :

Suppose `X` the interface that `A` and `B` implement.

```
public X getA(String x, String y){
   X a = new A();
   // specificities for A ...
   ... 
   // common processing
   commonForGet(a);
   return a;
}

public X getB(String x, String y){
   X b = new B();
   // specificities for B ...
   ... 
   // common processing
   commonForGet(b);
   return b;
}

private void commonForGet(X x){
   ...
}
```